# Why is this Arrayformula based vlookup with multiple criteria is not working?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I've followed the instruction, but it doesn't work in my situation and I wonder why.

This is the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B12&""&C12,F11:H29,3,0))
```

Here's a doc with a situation for tests: [File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B12:B29&C12:C29, {F11&G11, H11}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### No helper column all at once

> **Paste** this in `K11` [**Sheet Example**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQ3Z-4AipAzqWCE_8auT4Wl7S_iY4rp9d9050Y2cjwI/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(G12:G="",,VLOOKUP({F12:F&" "&G12:G},{{F12:F&" "&G12:G}, E12:E} ,2,0)
```

))

[image]

### With helper

> **Try** this. add a helper column with the formula `G11&" "&H11`, and paste the following formula in `K11`

```
=VLOOKUP(B12&" "&C12,F11:I29,4,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `1Item A` and `Cabeça` do not change, you can even hardcode them to avoid any helpers.

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B12:B29&C12:C29, {"1Item A", "Cabeça"}, 2, 0)))
```